# Build an array based on another class Constructor

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to create an array of Custom types in Swift based on another class. How can I pass the array count to the Shop class constructor below?
(count of customer array should be `cnt` in Shop class init)

```
class Customer {
    var id:Int
    var name:String
    var balance:Double=500
    init(Id:Int,Name:String, Balance: Double) {
        id=Id
        name=Name
        balance=Balance
    }
}

class Shop {
    let cus:[Customer]
    init(cnt:Int) {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: This question si very unclear. How are you supposed get the identifiers, names and balances for each custom, if the only thing you have is the `count`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the exact problem. From what I understood, you are simply trying to do something like this:

```
let customers = [Customer]()
customers.append(Customer(Id: 1, Name: "Mike", Balance: 100))
customers.append(Customer(Id: 2, Name: "Sara", Balance: 150))
customers.append(Customer(Id: 3, Name: "Dan", Balance: 120))

let shop = Shop(cnt: customers.count)
```

**Edit:** Based on your comment, you seem to want to populate the `cus` array in the `Shop` class based on the passed parameter to the constructor. Which is a weird decision because you want to create an array of a class with multiple properties (Id, Name, Balance) knowing only the count. What data will go to these properties?

I will assume you want to create a fake array of arbitrary `Customer` class.

```
class Shop {
   var cus: [Customer]
    init(cnt: Int) {
       cus = [Customer]()
       for i in 0..<cnt {
          cus.append(Customer(Id: i, Name: "name_\(i)", Balance: Double(i*100)))
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: the Shop class is auto-populated on the editor and unchangeable. The task is to build a Customer array dynamically based on cnt

Comment: @Ahmad You know that you cannot append to a `let` constant? You haven't even initialized it. Also, `..` operator does not exist. Not even speaking about `Int` to `Double` conversion problems.

Comment: @Sulthan Thanks for pointing out the bugs. Fixed.

Comment: Please, try to compile your code. Your array is not initalized. Why don't you use `cus = (0..<cnt).map { ... }` instead? Then a `let` would work.